# "No medium found" on external bootable HDD

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I've got a functioning bootable HDD which can run a copy of Windows 10 internally in a different machine. I've been trying unsuccessfully to mount it while it's externally attached to an Ubuntu machine via USB 3.0.

It shows up within /dev as `/dev/sdb`. Here is the output of my mounting attempt:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt
Error opening '/dev/sdb': No medium found
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': No medium found
```

Attempted solutions:

1. It (sdb) does not show up within `lsblk` or `sudo fdisk -l`.
2. `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` returns `mount: /mnt: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist`.

I'm running Mint 19.3, and the drive is a Seagate Barracuda 500 GB(ST500DM002).

I should note that there is no 'action' when I connect the drive -- no spin-up, no vibration, just dead silence.

How can I successfully mount the external drive? Does my problem have something to do with the bootable nature of the drive?

Comment: How is the drive connected? With a plain SATA to USB cable? Do you have an external power supply connected to the drive?

Comment: Yes, just a SATA to USB 3.0. This is a 3.5" drive, so I've just ordered a connector which allows a power supply. I'll make a corresponding answer if this works.